# NamedPipeServerStream and the await keyword

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, async-ctp

The article [C# Named Pipes with Async](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/441841/Csharp-Named-Pipes-with-Async), which was written for Async CTP library v3.0, uses code that does not compile with .NET 4.5.  Specifically

```
await pipe.WaitForConnectionAsync();

var message = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
```

fail because there is no such methods of [NamedPipeClientStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream.aspx).

Did something change in this regard between the CTP and the inclusion in .NET 4.5?  Am I missing a step to make this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `*Async` methods implemented in the Async CTP were temporary extension methods (i.e. they were extension methods that weren't added to the actual classes involved).  RTM "moved" those `Async` methods into the  instance methods on the applicable classes.  I assume that "move" wasn't as easy as copying the extension methods and some work/testing/acceptance was involved.  I'm gathering that some couldn't get moved for various reasons.  `NamedPipeServerStream.WaitForConnectionAsync` seems to be one of those methods.  You'll have to use the `TaskFactory.FromAsync` method to create a `Task` object from the `BeginWaitForConnection`/`EndWaitForConnection` pair to `await` on.  something like:

```
    await Task.Factory.FromAsync(pipe.BeginWaitForConnection,
        pipe.EndWaitForConnection, null);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pipe);
    await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
```

Comment: The only down side is having to do this manually means there is no support for using a cancellation token, which is the whole reason I was after these first class async methods on the pipe.

Comment: @donvan `BeginWaitForConnection` is not cancelable.  You could close the  pipe to "*cancel*" the wait; but is that really want you want to happen if when `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` is called, rendering the pipe useless?